# how to host mp3 file with koa framework

Tags: node.js, flutter, mp3, koa

I'm coding API server to be used in mp3 app.

I've used `koa-send`, `koa-static`, and just setting mp3 file to response-body.

But, no matter what API the app uses, the app stops. When I sent the length of the MP3 file separately because the app did not seem to accept the length of the MP3 file, it worked on iOS but not on Android.

If I post the same MP3 file on S3 and send request to that URL, it worked well, so I can't understand what the problem is.

Also, if I play music on Safari using my API, it comes out as a live broadcast. (using other sites, it comes in the form of mp3)

If it's a problem that you don't know how long it's playing, why is it the same file, but not on other sites, and not on my API?

**Other storage site:**

[image: other storage site]

**My API:**

[image: my API]

Comment: Are your images correct? I don't see anything having to do with those labels.

Comment: It is from a safari when each method is used.